# Order by meta_key in custom post type doesn't affect the query

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, meta-query

I'm trying to query custom posts ordering by a meta_key. But after WP_Query running, there isn't any change in sql query inside the order clause.

```
$args = array(
'post_type'   => 'event',
'post_status' => 'publish',

'meta_key' => '_start_eventtimestamp',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_datetime',
'order' => 'ASC',

'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => '_start_eventtimestamp',
        'value' => date('Ymd'),
        'compare' => '>='
    )
),

'posts_per_page' => '7',
);

$event_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

And when I get the generated query I got this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts
 INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
 INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )
 WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_start_eventtimestamp'
 AND ( ( mt1.meta_key = '_start_eventtimestamp' AND mt1.meta_value >= '20160930' ) ) )
 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'event' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
 GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order ASC LIMIT 0, 7
```

The order clause suffered no change.
Is there wrong in my script of order by meta_key?

Comment: AFAIK [ordering by `meta_value_datetime` doesn't exist.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look in the [WP_QUERY](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/) improvement and the [WP_QUERY Order & Orderby Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

```
$args = array( 
         'post_type'   => 'event',
         'post_status' => 'publish',
         'orderby' => array(
           'meta_key' => 'ASC'
          ), 
         'meta_query' => array(
           array(
             'key' => '_start_eventtimestamp',
             'value' => date('Ymd'),
             'compare' => '>='
          ),
       ),
    );
```

Hope it will work for you!