# How can I use two custom fields in WP Query

Tags: wp-query

How can I use two custom field in WP query, one ('edition') to select only some articles and another ('order') to sort articles. 
I try with this code, but sorting doesn't work.

```
// args
$args = array(
'posts_per_page'    => 6,
'post_type'         => 'post',
'post_status'       => 'future',
'meta_query'        => array(
                        array(
                            'key' => 'edition',
                            'value' => 1,
                         ),
                        ),
'meta_value_num'    => 'order',
'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
'order'             => 'ASC'
);
```

Comment: try with `'meta_key'    => 'order',` instead of `'meta_value_num'    => 'order',`

Comment: Instead of 'meta_key' => 'order', use 'orderby' => array(
           'meta_key' => 'ASC'). http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/241163/order-by-meta-key-in-custom-post-type-doesnt-affect-the-query/244216#244216

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this

```
$args = array(
'posts_per_page'        => 6,
'post_type'         => 'post',
'post_status'       => 'future',
'meta_key'          => 'listorder',
'order'             => 'ASC',
'orderby'           =>  'meta_value_num',
'meta_query'        => array(
                        array(
                            'key' => 'edition',
                            'value' => 1,
                         ),
                        ),
);
```